# In which directory is node running?

Tags: grep, find, ps, troubleshooting

In trying to figure out how some application that listens on port `8088` is running, I see that it has PID `15020`:

```
$ netstat -ntulp
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7070            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17593/node      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8088            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15020/node      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::8983                 :::*                    LISTEN      14995/java      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

I can see that it is a [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) application:

```
$ ps aux | grep 15020
ubuntu   15020  0.0  0.8 670940 32764 pts/4    Sl+  15:58   0:00 node app.js
ubuntu   15367  0.0  0.0   8080   620 pts/8    S+   16:33   0:00 grep --color=auto 15020
```

Now, how can I find where it is running? I don't see any `screen` or `tmux` sessions running. The creative person who designed this is unavailable for comment. What would be the next step? I did run `find / -name app.js` and that returned a few tens of results, not all of them are different versions of each other!

Grepping each of these found `app.js` files for text that I see returned on the 8088 interface shows that most of them match. **What would be a logical next troubleshooting step?**

Comment: Have a look at `ls -l /proc/15020/fd`: Is one of the entries `app.js`? If not: Where does `ls -l /proc/15020/cwd` point to? Is there an `app.js` in that directory?

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Thank you! `lsof` did lead me to the correct directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running lsof with the PID but chances are the file was opened at run time by the application but then not kept open;

`lsof -p 15020 | grep app.js`

Alternatively you could strace the application and look through the output for the full path to the file;

`strace -p 15020`

Comment: Thank you. In fact the `lsof` command led me to the directory holding the correct `app.js` file. Thank you!

Comment: `strace` doesn't make sense for that purpose if the application is already running as `strace` cannot go back in time. And if he knew how to start the process then he wouldn't ask which file is run.

Comment: The strace command is attaching to the already existing process, which if running and accessing the app.js will be outputted by strace.